# JavaFX TableView edit integer cell

Tags: java, javafx

In the official documentation of JavaFX on edit data a table view, there is example only for String, in my program I have two **INTEGER** columns, to edit them I use : select the row, click button, new form shows up, after the user fill it, hit ok, then data changes. Now I want to move from this to direct input in the table. How can I do this with Integer Columns.

```
    TreeTableColumn<RootMaster, Integer> dataColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>(rs.getString("tab.budget.table.column.budgeted"));
    dataColumn.setEditable(true);
    dataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<RootMaster, Integer>("budgetSum"));
    dataColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TreeTableCell<RootMaster, Integer> cell = new TreeTableCell<RootMaster, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return cell;
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
dataColumn.setCellFactory(
    TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
```

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error; it works fine for me. Are you sure you declared it as a `TreeTableColumn` and not a `TableColumn`? You have all the correct imports (`javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeTableCell` and `javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter`)?

Comment: TextFieldTableCell should  e use

Comment: @ChandanaSrilal I'm not sure I understand the comment, but you can only use a `TextFieldTableCell` in a `TableColumn`, not in a `TreeTableColumn` (this question is about a `TreeTableView`).